# Merging successive rows in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose a data frame like that input

```
    ** 0       1      2    3     4 **  
0  vina    dfaf   5654  gfh   Nan
1  qwe     Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan
2  bina    456    Nan   108   Nan
3  asd     Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan
4  nina    Nan    Nan   678   Nan
5  jkl     Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan
6  tina    Nan    Nan   Nan   768
7  QWE     Nan    Nan   Nan   Nan
```

output required from this data frame python:

```
    ** 0         1      2    3     4**   
0  vinaqwe    dfaf   5654  gfh   Nan
1  binapsd    456    Nan   108   Nan
2  ninajkl    Nan    Nan   678   Nan
3  tinaQWE    Nan    Nan   Nan   768
```

pls write the python for data frame look like this

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear whether `Nan` are real `NaN` or strings.

Anyway, you want a [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) every two rows, which you can obtain using [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) (or the index if a range index) and the floor division by 2:

```
(df.replace('Nan', '')
   .groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).sum()
   .replace('', np.nan)
)
```

Output:

```
         0     1     2    3    4
0  vinaqwe  dfaf  5654  gfh  NaN
1  binaasd   456   NaN  108  NaN
2  ninajkl   NaN   NaN  678  NaN
3  tinaQWE   NaN   NaN  NaN  768
```

Comment: Clever use of floor division

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, is a [`cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)/[`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) & [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) :

```
out = (df["0"].str.cat(df["0"].shift(-1)).to_frame().iloc[::2]
       .join(df.drop(columns="0"), how="inner")).reset_index(drop=True)
​
```

Output :

```
print(out)

         0     1     2    3    4
0  vinaqwe  dfaf  5654  gfh  Nan
1  binaasd   456   Nan  108  Nan
2  ninajkl   Nan   Nan  678  Nan
3  tinaQWE   Nan   Nan  Nan  768
```